# Why can I not access a property from a generic argument?

Tags: java, generics

Starting from a test case I'm trying to pass:

```
@Test
void testGetShare() {
    // Given
    Portfolio<Share> p = new Portfolio<>();
    Share shareA = new Share("Share A");

    // When
    p.buy(shareA);

    // Then
    Assertions.assertEquals(shareA, p.get("Share A"));
}
```

I'm trying to store asset objects in a Java HashMap where the assets provide a `getTitle()` method. However, I can't seem to be able to Access the items Methods.

```
public class Portfolio<Asset> {

    private Map<String, Asset> deposit = new HashMap<>();

    // Unable to Access 'title'    
    public void buy(Asset a) {
        deposit.put(a.title, a);
    }

    public Asset get(String title) {
        return deposit.get(title);
    }

}
```

I have two Kinds of assets which I would like to be able to place in (parametrized) deposits.

```
public class Asset { public String title; }
public class Share extends Assets { public Share(String title) {super(title);} }
public class Commodity extends Assets { public Commodity(String title) {super(title);} }
```

Why can I not Access the title of the asset Argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because of your line `public class Portfolio<Asset>` - here `Asset` (the same as commonly used `T`, `U` etc) is just generic declaration and it does not relate to your class `Asset`.

Just remove `<Asset>` from `Portfolio` class declaration.

More on Java Generics you could find here:

[java generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html)

But the comprehensive information is covered in this textbook:

[Java Generics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html)

---

To achieve what you want you need change your code to:

```
Portfolio<T extends Asset>
```

And:

```
public void buy(T asset)
```

Comment: Ok, but does it not evaluate to `buy(Share a)` or `buy(Commodity a)` when instantiating the Portfolio? That's why I have `Asset` as the Argument type

Comment: in your particular case - no.
I suppose you want smth like <T extends Asset>, where T could be either `Share` or `Commodity`

Answer (score 1):

The `Assert` generic type doesn't set any bound in `Portfolio`:

```
public class Portfolio<Asset> {}
```

It is like if you had declared :

```
public class Portfolio<Asset extends Object> {}
```

So the generic type `Asset` is bounded to `Object` and `Object` doesn't have any `title` field.

What you want is :

```
public class Portfolio<A extends Asset> {

    private Map<String, A> deposit = new HashMap<>();

    public void buy(A a) {
        deposit.put(a.title, a);
    }

    public A get(String title) {
        return deposit.get(title);
    }

}
```

You have to declare the upperbounded wildcard in the generic class declaration while you specify the concrete type only as you declare a variable typed with the generic class :

```
Portfolio<Share> p = new Portfolio<>();
```